# nil handling in swift(optional chaining)

Tags: swift, option-type

I am practicing Leetcode problems in swift.

I am facing issue about optional, I understood the concept.

but I don't know what is correct expression.

I implemented linked List problem, It has no problem but I have a problem when I check linked list contains answer.

Here is linked list will add two value (no problem)

```
  // Definition for singly-linked list.
      public class ListNode {
          public var val: Int
          public var next: ListNode?
          public init(_ val: Int) {
              self.val = val
              self.next = nil
          }
      }
    class Solution {
        func addTwoNumbers(_ l1: ListNode?, _ l2: ListNode?) -> ListNode? {
           var carry = 0
            var sum = 0
            let head = ListNode(0)
            var temp = head
            var l1 = l1
            var l2 = l2

            while (l1 != nil)||(l2 != nil)||(carry != 0) {

                if l1 != nil{
                    sum += l1!.val
                    l1 = l1?.next
                }
                if l2 != nil{
                    sum += l2!.val
                    l2 = l2?.next
                }
                carry = sum / 10
                sum = sum%10

                let newNode = ListNode(sum)
                temp.next = newNode
                temp = temp.next!
                sum = carry

            }
            return head.next
        }
    }
```

linked list contain values

```
    var l1 = ListNode(2)
    l1.next  = ListNode(4)
    l1.next?.next = ListNode(3)
    l1.next?.next?.next = ListNode(9)

    var l2 = ListNode(5)
    l2.next  = ListNode(6)
    l2.next?.next = ListNode(4)
```

code with issue (traverse linked list to shows values contained in linked list)

```
    var a = Solution()
    while( a.addTwoNumbers(l1, l2)?.next != nil){
        print(l1.val)
        //optional value error with a question mark.
        l1 = l1.next?

    }
    print (l1.val)
```

I got this error :

> error: day2_Add Two Numbers.playground:126:13: error: value of optional type 'ListNode?' not unwrapped; did you mean to use '!' or '?'?
>       l1 = l1.next
>               ^
>                   !

I understand that the last question mark shouldn't excuted, since it is an optional value.

but there is an error.

please let me understand why, and please show me how it can be corrected.
(please use optional chaining or binding with it)

Comment: I forgot to say that I used ! instead of ? mark.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

since .next can be nil . let l1 and l2 be optional.

so.

```
var l1:ListNode? = ListNode(2)
l1?.next  = ListNode(4)
l1?.next?.next = ListNode(3)
l1?.next?.next?.next = ListNode(9)

var l2:ListNode? = ListNode(5)
l2?.next  = ListNode(6)
l2?.next?.next = ListNode(4)

var a = Solution()
var l3 = a.addTwoNumbers(l1, l2)
while l3 != nil {
    print(l3?.val) // or print(l3!.val) because we sure it is not nil.
    l3 = l3?.next
}
```

update:
i fix your traversing code. the addTwoNumbers result should be saved first in separate variable, then traverse it. (in my case l3)

Comment: I tried your code, this will keep logging nil. why?

Comment: i succesfully run your code. but it seems you have error in your logic, so it does infinite loop. let me see.

Comment: i figured it out. to traverse the result, you should save the result first in separate variable, then traverse it.

Comment: your code was fine, If I just changed print(l3?.val) to print(l3!.val) Thank you very much!